Associative Matrix Multiplication in Econometrics/WLLN proof
I was working on an econometrics problem, and I was confused by some of the matrix algebra happening later on (Essentially, writing $XZ$ when $X \in \mathbb{R}^k, Z \in \mathbb{R}^k$).
Here's the problem: Consider the model $Y = X'\beta + e, Y \in \mathbb{R}, Z \in \mathbb{R}^k, X \in \mathbb{R}^k. X, Y, Z \in L^4. \mathbb{E}[ZZ']$ psd and $\mathbb{E}[ZX']$ is full rank. $\mathbb{E}[Ze] =0$. Given $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta} - \beta)\overset{d}\to N(0, V). $ (Where $\hat{\beta}$ is the IV estimator: $\hat{\beta} = (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_iX_i')^{-1}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_iY_i)$).
Define an estimator $\hat{V}$ for $V$ and show consistency. Essentially, this devolves into showing $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\hat{e}_i^2Z_iZ_{i}' \overset{p}\to \mathbb{E}[e^2 ZZ']$. In a solution along the way, I saw the algebra:
$$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\hat{e}^2_iZ_iZ_i' &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(e_i + (\beta - \hat{\beta})'X_i)Z_iZ_i'(e_i + X_i'(\beta - \hat{\beta})) \\ &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n e^2_iZ_iZ_i' + (\beta - \hat{\beta})'(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_iZ_iZ_i'X_i')(\beta - \hat{\beta}) + 2(\beta - \hat{\beta})'(\sum_{i=1}^nX_iZ_iZ_i'e_i) \end{align*}$$
My question is how we're even able to write something like $X_iZ_iZ_i'X_i'$, when $X \in \mathbb{R}^k, Z \in \mathbb{R}^k$? I thought matrix multiplication was always associative so we should write multiplication in a way that always makes sense. Am I missing something on the notation here? Thanks.

What role does $Z$ play in the model $Y = X'\beta + e$?

We're assuming that we may not have $\mathbb{E}[Xe]=0$, so we use $Z$ as an instrument. The estimator for $\beta$ is $\hat{\beta} = (\sum Z_iX_i')^{-1}(\sum Z_i Y_i)$

Is the problem from a textbook? At first read it seems the matrix multiplications you mention indeed do not work.

I should perhaps be more clear, so indeed $X_iZ_iZ_i^{\prime}X_{i}^{\prime}$ makes no sense, but the second line would be correct if you moved the sum outside, e.g. $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\beta-\hat{\beta})^{\prime} X_i Z_i Z_i^{\prime}X_i^{\prime}(\beta - \hat{\beta})$, since $X_i^{\prime}(\beta-\hat{\beta})$ as a whole is just a scalar (so its transpose is the same). The same can be done for the third term. Perhaps the rest of the derivation still makes sense if you would make this change?

Sorry for the many comments, I meant to write $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}((\beta-\hat{\beta})^{\prime} X_i) Z_i Z_i^{\prime}(X_i^{\prime}(\beta - \hat{\beta}))$
